# Get the value from an mxml to another (child to parent)

Tags: apache-flex

Hello I am quite new to flex and would like to know how do I get a value from another mxml.
I have a vaule in the child mxml that i would like to parse to the parent mxml .
Then use the vaule to create a search method.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, just create a public variable in the child that exposes the property to the parent.

Conceptually something like this in the child:

```
public var myValue : myType;
```

And the parent can access it like this:

```
 myChild.myValue;
```

Comment: It seems that din work, i tried declaring something like an id for the class in the parent.<fx:Declarations> <fx:XML id="model" source="c:\\workingVersions51.xml" > </fx:XML> <local:SparkOrgChartItemRenderer id="db"/> </fx:Declarations>

Comment: then i tried to use the value in a search function however it did not work.protected function Serachbutton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
   if (searchtb.text == ""){
    Alert.show("You didn't enter any search term", "Error");
   }
   else if (searchtb.text == )
    {
    currentState='organisation';
    }else 
    { 
     Alert.show("The search item is not found, would you like to search on a socail site", "Alert" ,Alert.YES|Alert.NO);
    }  
  }

Comment: You'll have to show code for us to offer an explanation as to why it worked in one situation, but not the other.

Comment: Oh i am looking for a solution cause in the child mxml is declared as private. static private const labels:Array = ["nameLabel", "nameLabel2", "positionLabel", "emailLabel", "phoneLabel", "mobilePhoneLabel"];      
      override protected function get labelItems():Array {return labels;} i would like to retrieve the namelabel

Comment: @Nicholas I suggest you read up on access modifiers and what they mean.  Here is some info from the Adobe docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html Read the info on public, private, protected, and internal.  While you're at it; you may consider picking up an Intro to programming book.